# HTTP Header Parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, http

In node.js, what lightweight ways are there to parse HTTP headers when the source is a buffer/string?
Something like using express.js or node's internal http module, but without creating actual network connections.

github / opensource, currently developer alternatives preferred to 'gist' type solutions, thanks

Comment: This project comes close to what I'm looking for: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-header-stack

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in HTTPParser that is used internally by node's [http module](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10/lib/http.js#L29).

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. It seems to be a rather poorly documented feature however. Do you have any information on how to properly use this module?

Answer (score -1):

You want to retrieve headers from a request without connecting? I'm not sure what you trying to do, but have you look into node's core module 'http'?

**Example:**

```
const http = require('http');

http.request({
    hostname: 'google.com',
    port: 80,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/'
}, (res) => {
    res.on('data', () => {});
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Retrieved headers: %O', res.headers);
    });
}).end();
```

Comment: Improper synax `var require('http');' Need to assign to a variable name...